# Kotlin, get запрос, совместимость с python

Tags: kotlin, api

Вопрос 1: Как я могу в котлине получить данные с API сервера? Условно у меня есть : http://193.164.16.86:3000/api/main
API сервер создан на python через flask.

Вопрос 2: Нужно ли мне json объект настраивать под kotlin? Это же два разных языка и разве kotlin примет словарь от python?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Какая разница какой язык, если json одинаковый везде

Comment: И два _разных_ вопроса нужно задавать в двух _разных_ вопросах. Я, конечно, поставлю тревогу "Необходимо конкретизировать" и ее, конечно, не заметят, но — на будущее — один пост-один вопрос.

Comment: @andreymal я очень слабый программист из-за нехватки практики и знаний. Я пишу суда, чтобы это узнать. Спасибо, что получил ответ на счёт второго вопроса!

Comment: @Глеб Вопросы тесно связаны между собой и я не думал, что это большая проблема задать два вопроса в одной теме, но вас услышал, спасибо.

Comment: все зависит от того, что вы пишите. если это Андроид-приложение, то вы можете получить данные от API либо нативно либо с помощью библиотек (например Ретрофит). ответ от API - это строка. она может быть как JSON, как XML и прочее (есть и более сложные примеры, но это не ваш вариант) но это все ровно строка. вы можете превратить ее в объект либо нативно либо с помощью библиотек (тот же Ретрофит).